# Python ginput not allowing new points to be plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code asks the user to digitize three points (using ginput), then should plot those points to the screen atop the imshow plot. It does not. Any ideas why?

```
from pylab import show, ginput, rand, imshow, plot
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

x1 = rand(103, 53) 
figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

imshow(x1)

# Get user input
x = ginput(3)
x = np.array(x)

# Plot the user's points to the screen
plot(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], 'k*', ms=50)
show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which way you are trying to plot, the star and the background or vice versa but you need to change the order of your calls.

```
plot(10, 30, 'k*', ms=100)
x = ginput(2)
imshow(x1)

show()
```

This will show a star then when you click two points show your rand data.

This is a nice example of using ginput taken from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ginput_manual_clabel.html):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def tellme(s):
    print(s)
    plt.title(s,fontsize=16)
    plt.draw()

##################################################
# Define a triangle by clicking three points
##################################################
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-1.,1.,-1.,1.])
plt.setp(plt.gca(),autoscale_on=False)

tellme('You will define a triangle, click to begin')

plt.waitforbuttonpress()

happy = False
while not happy:
    pts = []
    while len(pts) < 3:
        tellme('Select 3 corners with mouse')
        pts = np.asarray( plt.ginput(3,timeout=-1) )
        if len(pts) < 3:
            tellme('Too few points, starting over')
            time.sleep(1) # Wait a second

    ph = plt.fill( pts[:,0], pts[:,1], 'r', lw=2 )

    tellme('Happy? Key click for yes, mouse click for no')

    happy = plt.waitforbuttonpress()

    # Get rid of fill
    if not happy:
        for p in ph: p.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunninghamm. I really wanted to do what I said above in the description, by "then". In other words, I need to show the digitized points to the screen AFTER they've been dropped. Any ideas? I've updated my example code to show exactly what I need to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: @zbinsd, you're welcome. I see your code shows the x1 image, then after three click points it plots the stars on top of the x1 image, what part of that is incorrect?

Comment: Hmm. I do not see the three black stars where I clicked. If you do, I'll assume I have a system/version error on my end.

Comment: yes, I was scratching my head  rereading  your post trying to see how to interpret it differently! What does  matplotlib.__version__
output from python? Also are you using Ipython?

Comment: I have 1.3.1, Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.2 (x86_64) (Mac)

Comment: how exactly are you running the script?

Comment: It seems like a mac issue, just try changing the backend using  matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'TkAgg' in your script. If you have no luck I would maybe edit your question and include the fact is seems to be a mac issue, no doubt you won't be alone. If you feel it is better removing feel free.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a close before doing a imshow again over the image.

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = np.array(Image.open(sys.argv[1]))
plt.imshow(im)

x = plt.ginput(1)

plt.close()
plt.imshow(im)

plt.plot(x[0][0], x[0][1], 'rs')

plt.show()
```